# Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P01: relation "table" does not exist'

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

Im trying to autogenerate INSERT statements to populate a table from a given list of names and products using c# and Npgsql. Everything was working fine, so I decided to add couple of triggers that are needed for the purpose of this project. Triggers are relatively simple, but they performed flawlesly, while testing them on the sql console. Then, when I finally thought I was finished with the assignment, I tested it once again with my auto populating method in C#.I got this as an error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P01: relation "buyer" does not exist'

I've decided to test it once again on console, using the exact same INSERT statement, and again, it worked as it should have from the start. After good 3-4h spent googling and finding little to no answers, I've disabled all triggers and then the c# script worked without any problems.

So, to sum things up, query works with triggers flawlesly while typed in the console, but when used in C# it can't find the table?.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TBP_ERA".trigger_dohvati_prvi_datum()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  insert into "TBP_ERA".order(orderer,productname,productquantity) 
select buyer.id,buyer.productname,buyer.productquantity from buyer where buyer.ordercompleted=0 order by orderedat asc fetch first 1 rows only;
return null;
END;
$function$
;
```

And the trigger itself:

```
create
    trigger dohvati_datum after insert
        on
        "TBP_ERA".buyer for each row execute procedure trigger_dohvati_prvi_datum();
```

EDIT: 
C# part of the INSERT code

```
connection.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO \"TBP_ERA\".buyer(ID,name,productname,productquantity,ordercompleted)" +
                " VALUES(default,'" + buyer.Name + "','" + buyer.ProductName + "'," + buyer.ProductQuantity+",0);", connection);
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                string nekej = ex.ToString();
                throw;
            }


            connection.Close();
```

Comment: If they work in console then you don't have errors there but in the C# code that you haven't shown

Comment: Ty, I've edited my post

Comment: You shouldn't use `order` table name. Use `orders` because it's reserved for `order by` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to schema qualify `buyer` in the trigger function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TBP_ERA".trigger_dohvati_prvi_datum()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  insert into "TBP_ERA".order(orderer,productname,productquantity) 
select buyer.id,buyer.productname,buyer.productquantity from "TBP_ERA".buyer where buyer.ordercompleted=0 order by orderedat asc fetch first 1 rows only;
return null;
END;
$function$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error occurs when I run database function and inside this function I made mistake in table name. I paste function name instead of materialized view name. **Check your function body, run line by line and you find error**